# Failed to open package file due to error 0x800070035

Tags: batch-file, ssis, dtexec

Full error message:

```
Could not load package "\\File.dtsx" because of error 0xC0011002.
Description: Failed to open package file "\\File" due to error 0x80070035 "The network path was not found.".  This occurs when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can be the result of specifying an incorrect file name when calling LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect format.
```

This is a really strange issue. We have an SSIS package which is called via dtexec in a batch file. The SSIS package runs in 64 bit and we also use the 64 bit version of dtexec.

We have a task scheduler which calls the batch file which calls package. It looks like so:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn

dtexec.exe /f "\\local\it$\Development\.NET Projects\Reporting\DailyUpload_DEV\DailyUpload\File.dtsx"
```

However sometimes the package will run with no problems at all and sometimes it throws an error which you can see above.

Why is this happening?

We don't change accounts, we also use admin so I know it's not a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding net use before running the command so it makes that initial connection before pulling the file

```
Net use \\local\it$ "passwordhere" /USER:domain.username
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn
dtexec.exe /f "\\local\it$\Development\.NET Projects\Reporting\DailyUpload_DEV\DailyUpload\File.dtsx"
```

Comment: What would this accomplish?

Comment: I've had it before where it hasnt had chance to establish the connection properly to the remote resource so it has failed, hence why occasionally it works, so making that initial connection before it attempts the command would ensure it always has that connection ready to pull the files.